# Getting an OOM issue on the setContentView call in a java gradle android project

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, out-of-memory, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Intellij-idea and I had this project working without gradle, ran just fine and was functional. Migrated it to a gradle project (by just creating a new gradle android project and copying over the code) and now I'm getting this stack trace: (sorry it's so small...)

[image: stack trace for my OOM issue]

Here is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_background"
        android:contentDescription="@string/backgroundDesc"
        android:src="@drawable/title_image"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="7dp"
        android:paddingEnd="5dp"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/writtenBy"
        android:text="@string/gameBy"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:paddingStart="0dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

SplashScreen.java:

```
package com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SplashScreen extends Activity
{
    TextView writtenBy;
    private static int TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        writtenBy = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.writtenBy);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainMenu.class);
                startActivity(i);

                finish();
            }
        }, TIME_OUT);
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades" >

    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.internet"/>
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.access_network_state"/>
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/title_image"
            >
        <!--<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
                />-->
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category
                        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.MainMenu"
                android:label="Main Menu"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.SetUpNewGame"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.StartExistingGame"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.StoryBoard"/>
        <!--<activity
                android:name="com.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any insight here would be very much appreciated. I looked at all the other OOM issues I could find on StackOverflow here but couldn't find my actual issue. They are mostly about trying to create an image and mine is just happening on the call to .setContentView call in my SplashScreen.java file.

```
setContentView(R.layout.splash);
```

So I'm guessing it's the background causing the issue? But why wouldn't it cause an issue on a non-gradle project? Anyway, thanks for the input in advance.

Here's the specs for the title_image:
[image]

Comment: How big is `title_image` (in MB)?

Comment: "mine is just happening on the call to setContentView" - yes, but that ends up inflating a layout which will create views on your behalf - one of which happens to have a drawable resource named title_image.   Since this is your splash screen, it's probably safe to assume you haven't been running your app for a long time.  Chances are that title_image bitmap is too big.

Comment: title_image.png is 100 KB

Comment: So garima's answer worked for now, but I would like to figure out why it's so large in the first place if my image is only 100KB...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add this line to application class declaration into manifest file to request a larger heap size.

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Make change into manifest file code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades" >

    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.internet"/>
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.access_network_state"/>
    <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.write_external_storage"/>

    <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="17"/>
    <application
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/title_image"
            android:largeHeap="true">
        <!--<meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"
                />-->
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.SplashScreen"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action
                        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category
                        android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.MainMenu"
                android:label="Main Menu"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.SetUpNewGame"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.StartExistingGame"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name="com.thenewjonathan.gloryblades.StoryBoard"/>
        <!--<activity
                android:name="com.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />-->
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It would be better alternative to remove your OOM problem.

Comment: Your fix worked for the interim Garima... thanks so much! I'm having all kinds of other problems with the app now though. Background image not showing up for the splash screen, buttons not functioning the way the should... :( But that's all stuff I can figure out. Thanks so much again for your assistance!

Comment: Hi @Garima Mathur Do you think that increasing the heap size is going to slow down my app when it is deployed to a phone? I can't tell right now on my phone, but I only have the splash screen and a few menus done, nothing graphic intensive or processor heavy.

Comment: No its not responsible for your slow down app. It could be another reason for that like server response delay would be cause of that or it may be higher resolution drawable used in your app.